# Green functions on Riemann surfaces

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Rieamnnian surface without boundary and $\Delta_g$ be the Lapalce operator. We note $\lambda_i$ and $\phi_i$ the eigenvalues and  eigenunctions of $\Delta_g$. Let also $G_g$ be the Green function of $\Delta_g$ that is to say 
$$\Delta_g G_g( .  , y) =\delta_y -\frac{1}{vol(M)}$$
Formally, we have 
$$G_g(x,y)= \sum_{i>0} \frac{\phi_i(x) \phi_i(y) }{\lambda_i}.$$ 
My questions are: How strong is the convergence on the right hand side? Do someone have good references about this subject?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to clarify  your question. What do you mean by *how strong* is the convergence?  Are you referring to some norm, and if so, what kind of norm are you interested in? The operator $G_y$ acts between various  Sobolev spaces. In fact it is a pseudo-differentuial operator of order $-2$.

Consider the the difference

$$ R^L:=G_y-\sum_{0<\lambda_i\leq L}\frac{1}{\lambda_i}\phi_i(x)\phi_i(y),\;\; L\to \infty ?$$

It is also a pseudodifferential operator of order $-2$ so it defines bounded operators

$$R^L: L^{s,2}(M)\to L^{s+2,2}(M),\;\;s\in\mathbb{R}, $$

where $L^{2,s}$ denotes the Sobolev space of distributions  $s$-times differentiable with derivatives in $L^2$. Denote by $\Vert-\Vert_s$ the norm on $L^{s,2}$. We can define an operator norm

$$\Vert R^L \Vert_s = \sup_{\Vert\psi\Vert_s=1}\|R^L \psi\|_{s+2}.  $$

Are you interested in how fast $\|R^L\|_s\to 0$ for some $s$?

You can also think of $G_y$ as a distribution on $M\times M$ are you interested  in the convergence in Sobolev spaces of distributions on $M\times M$?

Two places you can look for the Green function.

M. Taylor: Pseudodifferential operators, Chap XII, or

Berligne-Getzler-Vergne: Heat Kernels and Dirac operators, Chap 3.

Comment: And, to suggest various corollaries: for fixed $x$ the sum for the Green's function converges in $y$ in a Levi-Sobolev space of index $1-\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. That "1" is "dimension/2", etc.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in the convergence with respect to Sobolev norm. Thank you for the answers, i will have a look to references and add comment if necessary.
 


Comment: You may want to use  Weyl's asymptotic estimates stating that  $\lambda_k\sim const. k$ as $k\to \infty$ for some positive and explicit constant $const$.